# Export variable from within while loop

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I want to export a variable from within a loop. I was not able to do it. I am not sure what is missing here.

Any suggestion would be great help

```
var="ahs tcs amq tos"

for i in ${var}
do
   ${i}_log="/var/tmp/pmp_${i}_log"
   #export ${i}_log
done
```

Comment: Is `$i` the value you expect it to be? Perhaps you should `echo` it to make sure.

Answer (score 3):

The idea is right, just use the `declare` variable to create variables on the fly. Also avoid using un-quoted variable expansion(`for i in ${var}`) for looping. Use a proper array syntax as

```
var=("ahs" "tcs" "amq" "tos")

for i in "${var[@]}"; do
    declare ${i}_log="/var/tmp/pmp_${i}_log"
    export "${i}_log"
done
```

---

As a side note for good practice, always specify the interpreter to run your script. It could be `#!/bin/bash` or `#!/bin/sh` or best do it by `#!/usr/bin/env bash`

Answer (score 0):

An alternative could be to use a single exported associative array instead of multiple variables:

EDIT: oops, this won't work since arrays can't be exported. :\

```
var="ahs tcs amq tos"

declare -A logs

for i in ${var}
do
  logs[$i]="/var/tmp/pmp_${i}_log"
done

echo ${logs[@]}
#### export logs
```

Also see [Inian's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44429188/3089519) for better practices for looping and arrays.

Comment: Unfortunately, arrays can't be exported

Comment: @Mike oh right... thanks. TIL

Doesn't help that bash doesn't throw any errors when I try to export it.

Comment: @Mike why would you say arrays cant be exported? 

Furthermore you can even export a newline or space separated list (depends on your `$IFS`) and parse it later with `real_list=($seperated_list)` You can then retrieve values by `first_var=${real_list[0]}`

Comment: @Mike you can export arrays with `export some_list=("${thelist[@]}")`

The main precaution to take is that if your IFS field seperator is a space for example, you may get incorrect data when parsing back into a list.

Answer (score 0):

This works on dash and bash (as long as the i's and the path to interpolate them into are reasonable):

```
#!/bin/sh
var="a b c d"

for i in $var
do
        export "${i}_log=/var/tmp/pmp_${i}_log"


        #test
        sh -c "echo \$${i}_log"
done
```

Comment: I tried this and its giving me the expected..Result...thanks for help

Comment: @SunilSharma I don't need thanks :D Gimme your upvotes and accepts! :D

Answer (score 0):

This can be done in one line without a loop

```
printf '%s\n' {ahs,tcs,amq,tos} | xargs -I {} bash -c 'export {}_log="/var/tmp/pmp_{}_log"; echo {}_log=${{}_log}'
```

or with a loop

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in {ahs,tcs,amq,tos}; do 
    #export
    export "${i}_log=/var/tmp/pmp_${i}_log"; 

    #test
    bash -c 'echo '"${i}_log"'='"\$${i}_log"; done
done
```

The reason  `${i}_log="/var/tmp/pmp_${i}_log"` failed is because `${i}_log` is unquoted and the syntax for exporting is `export somevar=somedefintion`. In order to dynamically generate the variable name, surround the statement in quotes so that it gets interpolated. ie. `export "${dynamic}_var=${dynamic}_definition"`

see http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/quoting